# Cell Only Shows Last String in Array

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I have an array of objects and I am trying to assign the proper index of the array to a certain cell as shown below.

My array:

```
let nflTeamData: [String] = ["New England Patriots", "Miami Dolphins", "New York Jets", "Buffalo Bills", "Baltimore Ravens", "Cincinnati Bengals", "Pittsburgh Steelers", "Cleveland Browns", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "New Orleans Saints", "Carolina Panthers", "Atlanta Falcons", "San Francisco 49ers", "Seattle Seahawks", "Arizona Cardinals", "Los Angeles Rams"]
```

Below is where add the dummy data into CoreData. I am printing out `teamName` below but unfortunately only getting the last item in my array (Los Angeles Rams) to populate the every row in the CollectionView. I know I need to be incorporating the indexpath of the array somehow, but not sure the proper way to access it outside collectionview delegate methods.

```
//MARK: CoreData
func addDummyData() {
    let moc = DataManager.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext

    for div in nflDivision {
        let division = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Division", into: moc) as! Division
        print(div)
        division.name = div
        addTeams(division: division)
    }

    DataManager.sharedInstance.saveContext()
}

func addTeams(division: Division) {
    let moc = DataManager.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext

    var i = 1
    while i < 5 {
        let team = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Team", into: moc) as! Team

        for (index, teamName) in nflTeamData.enumerated() {
            print(index, teamName)
            team.name = "\(teamName) - \(i)"
        }

        team.id = Int64(i)
        i += 1
        division.addToTeams(team)
    }
}

//MARK: CollectionView

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! StandingsCell
    let division = divisions[indexPath.section]
    let team = division.teams?[indexPath.row] as! Team
    cell.teamLabel.text = team.name
    cell.teamLogo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "nfl58")
    cell.winTextField.delegate = self
    cell.lossTextField.delegate = self
    cell.winTextField.tag = 0 //Increment accordingly
    return cell
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return divisions.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let division = divisions[section]
    return division.teams?.count ?? 0
}
```

**Current Output:**

[image: Controller]

Expected Output:

Only one team populating one row from the `nflTeamData` array mentioned above.

EDIT: I am now trying to implament the numberOfRowsInSection based on the value number from the dictionary below as a possible solution, but still am getting errors.

```
let nflDictionary: [String: String] = ["New England Patriots" : "1",
                                       "Miami Dolphins" : "2",
                                       "New York Jets": "3",
                                       "Buffalo Bills": "4",
                                       "Baltimore Ravens": "1",
                                       "Cincinnati Bengals": "2",
                                       "Pittsburgh Steelers": "3",
                                       "Cleveland Browns": "4",
                                       "Houston Texans": "1",
                                       "Jacksonville Jaguars" : "2",
                                       "Indianapolis Colts": "3",
                                       "Tennessee Titans": "4",
                                       "Kansas City Cheifs" : "1",
                                       "Denver Broncos": "2",
                                       "Oakland Raiders": "3",
                                       "Los Angeles Chargers": "4",
                                       "New York Giants": "1",
                                       "Philadelphia Eagles": "2",
                                       "Washington Redskins": "3",
                                       "Dallas Cowboys": "4",
                                       "Minnesota Vikings": "1",
                                       "Green Bay Packers": "2",
                                       "Detriot Lions": "3",
                                       "Chicago Bears": "4",
                                       "Tampa Bay Buccaneers": "1",
                                       "New Orleans Saints": "2",
                                       "Carolina Panthers": "3",
                                       "Atlanta Falcons": "4",
                                       "San Francisco 49ers": "1",
                                       "Seattle Seahawks": "2",
                                       "Arizona Cardinals": "3",
                                       "Los Angeles Rams": "4"
]
```

Comment: Your `addTeams` code makes no sense. Why do you have a `for` loop inside the `while` loop? Pay attention to what the `for` loop is doing each iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: the `while` loop is used to keep track of number of Teams that belong to each Division (4 total Teams per Division, 8 Divisions total). The `for` loop was an attempt to access each index within the `nflTeamData` array. I think I should be assigning `team.name = "\(nflTeamData[someIndex])"` but I don't know how to access the index of that array without using a for loop. Any suggestions @rmaddy?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to modify this method. Remove while statement and try as it is always updating the same value:-

```
func addTeams(division: Division) {
    let moc = DataManager.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    for (index, teamName) in nflTeamData.enumerated() {
        let team = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Team", into: moc) as! Team
            print(index, teamName)
            team.name = "\(teamName) - \(index)"
            team.id = Int64(index)
            division.addToTeams(team)
        }
}
```

Comment: This is close but it places everything under one section of my collectionView. I would like to populate only 4 items from the `nflTeamData` array in each section. This places all 16 items within the same section. This is why I need the while loop to be true when starting at 1 and is less than 5. Thanks @Hussain Shabbir

Comment: In that case you need to use the dictionary, where you can define your key as section and iterate the data and display on your section accordingly. Does it make sense?

Comment: makes logical sense, but not sure about how to go about implementing it. maybe you can provide some guidance?

Comment: Create your array of dictionary (key, value) where key will be your id and then inside your numberOfSections method display count based on id from the new dictionary. Now iterate your dictionary and get array of value and display in your rows.

Comment: i've tried messing around with adding a dictionary with no success. if you could perhaps provide so additional guidance with maybe an example it would be much appreciated! ive actually created key value pairs in a dictionary which are (id, teamName). My understanding is that if the id is equal to 1 it should go into the first slot in that section (each section only has 4 teams). i tried implamenting this in numberofrowsinsection but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
func addDummyData() {
    let moc = DataManager.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext

    var divisionLevel = 1
    for div in nflDivision {
        let division = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Division", into: moc) as! Division
        print(div)
        division.name = div
        addTeams(division: division, divisionLevel: divisionLevel)
        divisionLevel = divisionLevel + 4
    }

    DataManager.sharedInstance.saveContext()
}

func addTeams(division: Division, divisionLevel: Int) {
    let moc = DataManager.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var i = 1
    for var index in divisionLevel..<divisionLevel+4 {
        if nflTeamData.count >= index {
            let team = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Team", into: moc) as! Team
            team.name = "\(nflTeamData[index-1]) - \(i)"
            print("\(team.name)")
            team.id = Int64(i)
            division.addToTeams(team)
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
NFC North
Optional("New England Patriots - 1")
Optional("Miami Dolphins - 2")
Optional("New York Jets - 3")
Optional("Buffalo Bills - 4")
NFC East
Optional("Baltimore Ravens - 1")
Optional("Cincinnati Bengals - 2")
Optional("Pittsburgh Steelers - 3")
Optional("Cleveland Browns - 4")
...
```

Comment: this didnt work. i tried messing with in my project and in playground and it repeats the id for each team (i.e. ["id": "1", "name": "New England Patriots"],  , ["id": "2", "name": "New England Patriots"], ["id": "3", "name": "New England Patriots"], ["id": "4", "name": "New England Patriots"])

Comment: Can you please provide the sample output what you are trying to get?

Comment: Under header of AFC East (as shown in the picture above), the first four teams from my array should be listed (New England Patriots in the 1st red cell, Miami Dolphins in the 2nd red cell, New York Jets in the 3rd red cell, and Buffalo Bills in the 4th red cell. This is the same as the 0 -3 in my `nflTeamData` array.  But I am currently not getting that. I am either getting back16 items from the `nflTeamData` or 4 items that are labeled the same team .

Comment: under AFC North it would continue to move down the same `nflTeamData` array and would populate (Baltimore Ravens in the 1st red cell under the AFC North section Header, Cincinnati Bengals in the 2nd red cell, Pittsburgh Steelers in the 3rd red cell, and Cleveland Browns in the 4th)

Comment: You want the output like this : `[["id": 1, "name": "New England Patriots - 1"], ["id": 2, "name": "Miami Dolphins - 2"], ["id": 3, "name": "New York Jets - 3"], ["id": 4, "name": "Buffalo Bills - 4"], ["id": 1, "name": "Baltimore Ravens - 1"], ["id": 2, "name": "Cincinnati Bengals - 2"], ["id": 3, "name": "Pittsburgh Steelers - 3"], ["id": 4, "name": "Cleveland Browns - 4"], ....]`

Comment: yep, that looks like the output im going for

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: it still is adding all the the teams to one header, not 4 teams per header. while your solution works in playgrounds it doesnt translate to my current setup given its not incorporating the `division.addToTeams(team)` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153821/discussion-between-a2b123-and-vini-app).

Comment: This is close but the teams are still out of order. The flow should be `NFC NorthOptional("New England Patriots - 1")
Optional("Miami Dolphins - 2")
Optional("New York Jets - 3")
Optional("Buffalo Bills - 4")
NFC East
Optional("Baltimore Ravens - 1")
Optional("Cincinnati Bengals - 2")
Optional("Pittsburgh Steelers - 3")
Optional("Baltimore Ravens - 4")`
...